# How to use C macro's (#define) to alter calls but not prototypes

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005, c-preprocessor

Older code in our application contains calls to `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`. With our updated code, our own implementations are called instead of the standard runtime ones. Examples are shown below,

```
#define malloc(s) OurMalloc(s)
#define free(p)   OurFree(p)
```

This works fine for the updated code and for the newer C++ code we simply implement global `new` and `delete` operators, so the C++ solution is 'cleaner'.

The problem is that we now have to include a 3rd party library, which has classes that contain methods that have names like `malloc` and `free`, e.g.

```
   class ABC
   {
      public:
      ...
      void free (char *p);
   };
```

If the free method of the class has the same number of arguments, the C/C++ preprocessor simply replaces all occurrences of `free` by `ourFree`, even in the class definition, even when calling the method free of the class `ABC`.
So the class definition above and the following call:

```
ABC abc;
abc.free(p);
```

are replaced by,

```
class ABC
   {
   public:
      ...
      void OurFree (char *p);
   };

ABC abc;
abc.OurFree(p);
```

Which may compile, but which doesn't link of course.

If `ABC::free` has a different number of arguments than the standard free, the compiler still gives a warning. we would like to avoid them.

Some alternative solutions are:

- undefining our defines in the beginning of the 3rd party include file and redefining it later
- make sure that the 3rd party include file is always included before our own define's

But even then, if our code is required to call these malloc or free methods of the 3rd party classes, the preprocessor will still alter the calls, unless we write all calls like this:

```
(abc::free)(p)
```

Is there a way to tell a C/C++ preprocessor define that?

- only pure C-calls must be replaced
- prototypes MUST NOT be replaced
- methods in classes MUST NOT be replaced

Comment: C does not support the 'class' construct or the '::' scoping operator; what you are illustrating is C++ code.

Comment: Isn't this the use case for namespaces? or are those not respected by the preprocessor?

Comment: @Jonathan, we have a mix of C and C++ code, but to ease transition from C to C++, we decided (years ago) to compile all C files as C++ files.

Comment: I thought I had a solution using templated functions, but that also seem to give problems (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319772)

Comment: @Dana: no, the preprocessor does simple text replacement, and doesn't know about namespaces or any other language construct.

Comment: Given that you compile the files with the C++ compiler, and the 'C' files seem to contain C++ code, you should give up on the fiction that the files that once contained C still contain C; what you are showing is C++.  And solutions with templates etc are simply impossible in C; C does not have templates (or ...).  You will get better answers if you don't try to claim that your code is C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessor know nothing about about scope and semantic. So short answer - no, you can't do that.

But, you can use `#undef free` in library modules. On other side - this will not help, if you call methods `abc.free()` from your code.

Comment: I'm afraid this was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about only defining those replacements for C and not C++:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#  define malloc(s) OurMalloc(s)
#  define free(p)   OurFree(p)
#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't help as all the code is compiled as C++ code, even the older C-only parts.

Comment: Then just replace top-level malloc and remove all the pre-processor games.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just define your own malloc and free functions instead of using macros.

So, change:

```
void *OutMalloc (size_t s)
```

to:

```
void *malloc (size_t s)
```

in the same way that you can overright operator new and delete.

I think, although I may be wrong, the linker will look in object files for symbols before looking in libraries.

Comment: We used to do this in the past, but this only works if you statically link in the C/C++ run time libraries (and you pass your own 'overruled' object files to the linker before the run time library).  It doesn't work if you dynamically link with the C/C++ run time DLL's.

Comment: Doesn't Windows have something along the lines of LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: LD_PRELOAD seems to be Unix only, not Windows.  Although I found some useful information related to DLL injection.